# Maximum subarray problem

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

Given a 2d array N*M made of only 1's and 0's . I need to find a maximum subarray(square or rectangle) between two rows of the given 2d array which has all ones inside it.
I need to find count of ones in this maximum subarray

EXAMPLE :
Let N=4 and M=5 and the array be

1 0 1 1 0

1 0 1 1 1

0 1 1 1 1

0 0 0 0 1

Now if their are Q(say here it be 2) queries each describing upper and lower row between which we need to find this subarray.

Query 1 : 1 1(means start at row 1 and end also at row 1).Then we can clearly see answer will be 2

Query 2 : 2 3(means start at row 2 and end at row 3).Then answer will be 6 here.

Now,if queries can be very large in number(say upto 10^6) .How to tackle this problem

Comment: How large N and M can be, is this online judge problem?

Comment: @Ashot Each N,M can be as large as 10^3.So perhaps their can be some Dynamic solution to this problem

Comment: @Ashot Nopes, its an question i was asked in an interview.I thought about it but cant tackle it in less than O(N^3).So i want some better approach to tackle this problem

Comment: You are doing $O(N^3)$ calculations per query yes? Can you write that algorithm?

Comment: @Ashot Not O(N^3) per query.I am enumerating all ranges in a 2d array in O(n^3).And then doing query in O(1).

Answer (score 0):

$O(n^3*m^3)$ full scan solution can be simplified to $O(n^2*n^2)$ by next approach:

Subarray $[i, i+a][j, j+b]$ is feasible if next subarrays are all feasible:

$[i, i+a-1][j, j+b-1]$

$[i+a, i+a][j, j+b-1]$

$[i, i+a-1][j+b, j+b]$

So using dynamic programming - feasibility check is O(1) if you are caching intermediate results;

If you will be caching feasibility of smaller arrays during calculation - this will take $O(n^2*n^2)$